# Cannot get a Koji Build system work

Tags: apache, ssl, centos6, koji

I setup the **koji** build environment in a **Centos6 Machine server** as suggested by the documentation (http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Koji/ServerHowTo).
I could properly access the Koji Web using http. Yet I am facing an **SSL certificate trouble** when switching to https:

Client Browser error produced by Mozilla FireFOx:

```
SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters. (Error code: ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert)
```

- Having enabled two admin users, I get a Koji secific error when running the command:

  su kojiman; koji call getLoggedInUser

Errors under : kojiman:

```
Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')]
```

#

su kojiadmin; koji call getLoggedInUser
Errors under: kojiadmin

```
Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_READ_BYTES', 'sslv3 alert bad certificate'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL3_WRITE_BYTES', 'ssl handshake failure')]
```

---

While in httpd ssl log I have the following:

############################"

SSL erros:

```
[Wed Feb 05 18:37:28 2014] [error] [client 46.21.193.155] Certificate Verification: Error (19): self signed certificate in certificate chain
[Wed Feb 05 18:44:06 2014] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `kojihub' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Feb 05 18:44:06 2014] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `kojihub' does NOT match server name!?
```

- When I test the certificate I get with openSSL:

  openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -tls1 -CAfile /etc/pki/koji/kojihub.pem

I indeed get:

```
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate

verify return:1
139736479307592:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1256:SSL alert number 40
139736479307592:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:596:
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Was using the wrong certificate for the main builder.
Changed in kojid.conf